# Control multiple clocks by changing it in one class

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, mockito, clock

Is there a way to change the time in all classes by changing the clock in one class?

Say I have a test class A and a class B. I want to change the clock in the test class (A) so that it would automatically set B’s clock to the same time.

I Have tried hard coding the clocks in Both classes but it doesn’t really work for the test case I’m writing. Should I make a static clock class?

Comment: It is nice having a Clock following the database time, but this case I did not have yet. Look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-override-system-time

Comment: you can use static attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think you could creating a singleton to share in your case tests.

Create any singleton to be shared

```java
// this class can be any shared value
public class AnySingleton{
    
    private static AnyClock clock;
    
    public static AnyClock retrieveSingletonClock(){
    
        if( clock == null ){    
            clock = new AnyClock();
        }
        return clock;
    }

}
```

Use in tests

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class A {
    
    private AnyClock anyClock;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        this.anyClock = AnySingleton.retrieveSingletonClock();
    }
    
    ...
}


@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class B {
    
    private AnyClock anyClock;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        this.anyClock = AnySingleton.retrieveSingletonClock();
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Note: Check if you really need associate unit tests because they should be treated on their own. Unit tests are different to integrated one.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, i'll try it out thanks. I'll also see if there is a way I can change the system's  time instead

Comment: Tried that and it works thanks a lot @Dilermando Lima